# Windows Mobile - Emulator Error

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I'm getting the error below when trying to use the Windows Mobile 6 emulators please advise how I can fix:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

### The operation could not be completed

### OK

Using Windows 7, VS.Net 2008, WinMobile 6 Pro SDK

Comment: We need more information

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us what you do exactly? (For example; try to run an application via Visual Studio -> Build (F5))

Further, are you sure there's no error message shown in the statusbar, Immediate Window, Output Window? If so, please post them.